# Python: Unbound Methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

To preface here is the error I receive:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "TestR.py", line 13, in __init__
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title = "Input Data", size = (1250, 
    750))
    TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Frame instance as 
    first argument (got nothing instead)`

when I type in this:

```
j = Test(None, "hello")
```

with this code:

```
  import wx


class Test(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title = "Input Data", size = (1250, 750))
```

Comment: That's not how you use `super`. The first argument is the name of the class you're writing, not the superclass. Also, if your base classes were not designed to work together in multiple inheritance, you can't use `__super__` for the `__init__` calls. (In the case where they *are* designed to work together like that, you only make one `__super__` call.)

Comment: Edited - Still a problem.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Why are you inheriting from both ``Data`` and ``Frame`` classes anyway? You can use the "Adapter Pattern" here or "Dependency Injection"

Comment: That is the entire  traceback

Comment: No it's not. Show us everything from `Traceback (most recent call last):` to `WhateverError: some message here`.

Comment: I'll look into those methods of implementing multiple classes James Mills, thank you, but I first want to fix this problem.

Comment: The problem is Multiple Inheritance and the classic Diamond Problem. Going down the path of mixing multiple classes will not end well.

Comment: Edited again for more traceback

Comment: Also, that is false James Mills, because I can remove Data and still recieve the same error - it is not a multiple classes problem and does not involve the diamond problem.

Comment: Huh. That is damn weird. Even with multiple inheritance conflicts, it's hard to see how that error could happen. Can you try to [strip your code down to the bare minimum that runs and reproduces the error, then post that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's okay if all functionality is lost in the process, as long as the bug is visible.

Comment: Stripped~ Down to minimum

Comment: The [docs](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Frame-class.html) say `wx.Frame.__init__` takes a bunch more arguments than you're supplying: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Frame-class.html Also, can you show the traceback corresponding to the stripped-down code?

Comment: Added traceback again and yeah, but they have default values.

Comment: How is the error happening on line 13? The code you've posted doesn't have 13 lines in it.

Comment: When I create a new docoment it adds some comments at the top

Comment: Haha silly me, had to create an instance of app! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines.

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
Test(None, "hello")
app.MainLoop()
```